# Using MKL library create random matrix

Tags: c, matrix, random, intel-mkl

When I use ***vdRngUniform()*** routine to create a random matrix, the maximum size matrix I can use only 40000 x 40000. Do we have any other routine from MKL to create with the bigger size? I can create by the normal way on C but it affects performance. So please guide me with other routines from MKL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is also being addressed on the Intel MKL forum, I am posting the responses here in case others are interested.
Link to Intel MKL Forum: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/851713

We suggest to continue use vdRngUniform() routine with generation by blocks.
You can generate matrix of the needed size block by block, as shown below.

Also, not sure if using RNGUniform is important to your case, but you may take a look at the https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-lagge routine which generates M x N matrix. You may link with ILP64 mkl API and generate matrix beyond of 40k by 40K

```
VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
vslNewStream( &stream, BRNG,  SEED );       

const int64_t size = 40000*40000;
const int64_t block_size = 1000;

double* matrix;
matrix = (double*) malloc (size*sizeof(double));

for(int64_t i = 0; i < size; i+=block_size) {
        vdRngUniform( VSL_RNG_METHOD_UNIFORM_STD, stream, block_size, matrix + i, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

free(matrix);
vslDeleteStream( &stream );
```

Answer (score 0):

one note should be added - working with such problem sizes ( > 40k), users have to link with the MKL ILP64 version of libraries and use -DMKL_ILP64 compiler options accordingly.